# Galleria load images from folder

Tags: gallery, photo, galleria

How can i configure galleria image gallery (http://galleria.io/), to load images from a specified folder?
This way if I want to upload a new photo, I don't need to add a new img src to my html file.

Comment: you'll need software that runs server-sided, such as node.js, php, java or ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no ability to see the file system on a server. There is no real way to do this. You could, however, have a js file in that folder that keeps an index of all the images in that folder. Then you could load that file first and then dynamically load the images from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to simply upload images to a folder (like with your mobile phone when you're on the road) and have galleria display all the images inside this folder, you could use a htaccess file, split your page into header.html and footer.html. 
The htacess file if configured correctly will read all the files in the directory, sort it according to your settings (like date descending) and put the img src code in the final html document. The galleria script goes into the footer.html and will read the img list that the htaccess file has created.